# Invalid date error when modifying Big Query Table schema from string (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TIMEZONE) to date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with a string format column where value are like this :

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TIMEZONE` so for example `2015-08-27 19:42:53 UTC`

UTC is the only timezone. I want to rewrite this string column as a date column. I have an `Invalid date error` when I'm trying to run the following query to export the result in a new table

```
SELECT
  CAST(my_date AS DATE),stuff_here,stuff_here
FROM
  `table`
```

What should I do in order to properly change the type of this column from string to date ?

Comment: Have you tried PARSE_TIMESTAMP? You can cast the timestamp to a date.

Comment: Instead of CAST ?

Comment: Parse as a timestamp, then cast as a date.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to write this logic:

```
select CAST(substr('2015-08-27 19:42:53 UTC', 1, 10) AS DATE)
```

Because I am in New York, I would instead write:

```
select date(timestamp('2015-08-27 19:42:53 UTC'), 'America/New_York')
```

This distinction has been very important in our using data -- the difference between days at the Greenwich Meridian versus in our local area.

Comment: Why is the difference exactly between the CAST/DATE method and the data/timestamp method ? Why we don't need to substr with timestamp ?

Comment: @SimonBreton . . . Because timestamps contain time components and dates do not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(my_date,1,19) AS DATE,stuff_here,stuff_here
  FROM `table`
```

This assumes that you are not interested in the timezone part.